# Very long boot up in Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS desktop

Tags: boot, 20.04, systemd, services

I am experiencing very slow boot up times. It takes about 2 minutes to fully boot up.
Is there a way to decrease the total boot time?

Here is the log from systemd-analyze:

```
tanmay@tanmaysinha123:~$ systemd-analyze
Bootup is not yet finished (org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager.FinishTimestampMonotonic=0).
Please try again later.
Hint: Use 'systemctl list-jobs' to see active jobs
(base) tanmay@tanmaysinha123:~$ systemctl list-jobs
JOB UNIT                                 TYPE  STATE  
95  systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service start waiting
2   multi-user.target                    start waiting
145 snapd.autoimport.service             start waiting
1   graphical.target                     start waiting
113 snapd.seeded.service                 start running

5 jobs listed.
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several actions you can do to improve boot time like *disable not necessary services and not necessary snaps*.

You can try  first verify which service / snap take longer time with:

```
lsblk -f 

systemd-analyze blame

systemd-analyze critical-chain
```

Very often **services** as e.g. Network manager takes a lot of time (in this case waiting for a internet connection) during booting and may be turned off to speed up boot time.

you can disable it with:

```
sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```

Don’t worry, once you log in, you’ll have wifi
working normally, so only when you've completed boot you can switch on your internet connection.

If you want to revert the change, you can use this command:

```
sudo systemctl enable NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```

*You have to be careful disabling services because It may have dangerous consequences. It is very important that you know well what you are doing and the risk to make your system instable.*

Check also **installed snaps** because they take a long time during booting to be mounted, so you can verify if you have snaps not used and old versions installed marked with "disabled" to gain free disk space with:

```
snap list --all
```

you will have a list like this:

```
Name                             Version                     Rev   Tracking         Publisher   Notes
canonical-livepatch              9.5.5                       95    latest/stable    canonical✓  -
core                             16-2.46.1                   9993  latest/stable    canonical✓  core
core18                           20200724                    1885  latest/stable    canonical✓  base
gnome-3-28-1804                  3.28.0-17-gde3d74c.de3d74c  128   latest/stable    canonical✓  -
gnome-3-34-1804                  0+git.3556cb3               60    latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
gtk-common-themes                0.1-36-gc75f853             1506  latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-14-core18  5.68.0                      4     latest/stable    kde✓        -
okular                           20.04.0                     98    latest/stable    kde✓        -
rambox                           0.7.6                       14    latest/stable    ramboxapp✓  -
snap-store                       3.36.0-80-g208fd61          467   latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
snapd                            2.46.1                      9279  latest/stable    canonical✓  snapd
```

I saw that additional snap I had installed slow down boot time so at the end I've removed all kde snaps that I've had installed leaving only canonical system snaps.

If you want for  example unistall kde snaps you can type command like:

```
sudo snap remove okular
sudo snap remove kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-14-core18
```

In my case leaving only rambox snap installed by myself I've checked my boot time:

```
systemd-analyze
```

the output is:

```
Startup finished in 9.042s (firmware) + 4.861s (loader) + 3.600s (kernel) + 24.641s (userspace) = 42.146s 
graphical.target reached after 24.366s in userspace
```

At the end I've reached a boot time of about 25 seconds.